# How to append a "timer" inline with a print statement?

Tags: python

I didn't actually able to come up with the best suitable title for this. But the problem is: I have this little function, which prints a count up timer on the screen:

```
def timer(x):
  for i in range(1,x):
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('\r  \r')
```

How can I append the timer at the end of a print statement, like: `Now counting.... 3`? I tried this:

```
sys.stdout.write('Now counting..... ')
timer(6)
```

But it's printing the timer in the beginning of the line, replacing first two characters. Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not pass your message to the `timer` function?

```
def timer(message, x):
  for i in range(1,x):
    sys.stdout.write("\r%s%d" % (message, i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write('\r  \r')
...


timer('Now counting..... ', 6)
```

Comment: Silly me! didn't actually think about this trick. worked just fine. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the `\r` as that moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. If you want to overwrite you could try using a backspace instead (`\b`).

Comment: Thanks! that indeed solves the problem but, the [new] problem is now, the next statement is also being printed in the same line. I know I can insert `print " "` to avoid that but is there any other way of doing that? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: You could add a `print` statement at the end of your function (outside the for loop). Why do you need another way? What's wrong with `print`?